# MySQL Join returning 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with an SQL query. This is my first time using advanced SQL operations like this so it could be that I'm missing something basic. I am running this query:

```
SELECT countries.id, 
countries.name, 
AVG(users.points) AS average 
FROM countries 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON countries.id = users.country 
ORDER BY average DESC
```

This query is only returning 1 row and it's not following the ORDER BY because the returned value is . My aim with this is to get all the records in the Countries table and get the average of the points awarded to the users from each country. I want it to return those countries which do not have users assigned to them as well. I have done this in 2 queries and it worked but I thought that maybe I could do only one query. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only returning one row because it is an aggregation query without a `group by`.  Perhaps you mean:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, AVG(u.points) AS average 
FROM countries c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON c.id = u.country 
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
ORDER BY average DESC;
```

The `AVG()` makes this an aggregation query.  Without the the `group by`, SQL interprets it as returning one row summarizing all the rows.  MySQL supports an extension to the SQL standard where columns in the `select` do not have to be in the `group by`.  In most databases, you query would return an error.

Comment: This worked even though I left out the 'c' and used 'countries' instead. However, I think the answer should contain ON c.id - u.country.

Comment: @user2604185 . . . I find it easier to write and read queries that use table aliases.  However, they are not always needed (sometimes yes, but not in this case).

Comment: Should ON c.id = c.country be u.country?